# Bitwise not operation on a string of bits

Tags: java

I have a string with the value `0111000000`. How can I perform a bitwise not operation on this string?

If I convert it to an integer, use the `~` operator and convert it back to a binary string, the resulting string has extra bits. I want the output to be exactly `1000111111`.

The following code works fine, but it's not a good method. Is there another better way of doing this?

```
   String bstr="";
   while(m!=str.length())
   {             
        char a=str.charAt(m);
        if(a=='1')
        {
             a='0';
             bstr=bstr+a;
             m++;   
        }
        else
        {
             a='1'; 
             bstr=bstr+a;
             m++;
         }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i]=='0' ? '1' : '0';
    }
    s = new String(a);
```

this also works fine

```
    int i = ~Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
    String tmp = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    s = tmp.substring(tmp.length()- s.length());
```

Comment: Good but `a[i] ^= 1;` is neater.

Comment: what does the `& 0x3FF` do?

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of how many bits there are in your bit-string. After converting to an integer and using a `~value` operation to flip the bits, use a bit-mask to remove the unwanted `1` high-end bits.

Say for example your bit-string has a fixed 10 bits. Then you can mask off the unwanted high-end bits with: `value & 0x2ff`.

If the number of bits in the bit-string is variable:

`value & ((1 << nBits) - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

[`StringUtils.replaceChars`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceChars%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) from common-lang might help here:

```
StringUtils.replaceChars("0111000000", "01", "10");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use string builder so you are able to change individual bits without creating many many garbage strings. Also you can flip single bits using XOR:

```
b ^= 1;
```

Which works on both binary and ASCII values of digits.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will work:

```
String result = Integer.toBinaryString(~(Integer.parseInt("0111000000",2)));
```

converts binary String to int, use bitwise not operator to invert, then convert back to binary string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `XOR` operation

```
public String xorOperation(String value) {
    String str1 = value;
    long l = Long.parseLong(str1, 2);
    String str2 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        str2 = str2 + "1";
    }
    long n = Long.parseLong(str2, 2);
    long num = l ^ n;
    String bininaryString = Long.toBinaryString(num);
    System.out.println(bininaryString);
    return bininaryString;
}
```